# ¿Es posible editar CSS desde Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, css, nodejs, socket.io

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema de baneo en un chat y necesito saber si se puede modificar css desde nodejs, podria hacerlo con socket.io pero creo que es innecesario pero si no se puede modificar no me queda otra.

Comment: NodeJS se ejecuta en el servidor, no soy experto, pero no creo que se pueda, la mejor opción es establecer una conexión de socket y cambiarlo con JS desde el cliente

Comment: En vez de pensar en modificar un css deberias pensar es en anadirle de fabrica esos estilos que requieras al CSS asi no los uses, ya que por ejemplo puede que el usuario no este baneado y tenga cierto CSS, pero y que pasa si el usuario termina baneado?, vas a estar quitando y anadiendo css cada vez que un usuario sea baneado o desbaneado?, creo que esto no es optimo... a no ser de que estes pensando en anadir o quitar clases CSS desde javascript, en cuyo caso no estarias modificando directamente el archivo CSS.

Comment: Por cierto... si es un chat lo que dice @anythingg es lo mejor, tambien concuerdo con el, sin embargo sere un poco mas especifico, deberias crear un evento enlazado entre el socket cliente y el socket servidor para poder en el cliente hacer el cambio de estado en tiempo real.